# How can I change object image in MapInfo using MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I need to change the image of the objects which are in the Selection Table using MapBasic functions. When I say *"Image"* I mean point object icon on the map.

Comment: You'll need to expand a bit on this - what exactly do you mean by "the image"

Comment: My task is to replace standart icon of the point object by the image or symbol.

Comment: Are you trying to replace them with a custom image that you have made? Do you want to end up with them all the same or are you trying to change individual points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly full of best practice but this code should change the current selection to an image of a fire hydrant.  Just set NewSymbol to what ever you want to display.  You may want to use MakeSymbol instead of MakeCustomSumbol if by "image" you meant a font symbol rather than an image symbol.

```
Include "mapbasic.def"

Declare Sub Main

Sub Main

Dim RowNumber as integer
Dim NewObject as object
Dim XCoord as float
Dim YCoord as float
Dim NewSymbol as symbol

' Note no protection to ensure if you have a selection.

' Change this to be the desired symbol.  Must be in MapInfo custom symbol folder. Use MakeSymbol for other symbols.
NewSymbol = MakeCustomSymbol("FIRE2-64.BMP", BLUE, 64, 0)


' set the coordinate system to be the same as the table.
run command  "set map "+ tableinfo(selection, tab_info_coordsys_clause)


'Loop over rows in selection
For RowNumber = 1 To SelectionInfo(sel_info_nrows)
    ' Get a row
    fetch rec rownumber from selection
    ' Update point to be new symbol
    XCoord = ObjectGeography(selection.obj, obj_geo_pointx)
    YCoord = ObjectGeography(selection.obj, obj_geo_pointy)
    Create Point Into Variable NewObject (XCoord, YCoord) Symbol NewSymbol
    ' Update row
    Update Selection Set obj = newobject where RowID = RowNumber    
next

End Sub
```